# Why do Bar Pie Chart values not line up?

Tags: chart.js

I'm working on a Bar Pie Chart but my values are not lining up.  For example, Red data is clearly larger then blue, but blue value is higher.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data is correct, chart.js doesnt show the area as more, it uses the angle of the circle , which normally would also divede the area normally. And as you can see the angles are correct so to fix your issue you will have to write a custom controller that draws your chart. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html